# What permission a user should have in order to change the territory in Opportunity manually?

Tags: opportunity, sharing, access, insufficient-privileges, territory

I have a business user who is getting Read/Write access to opportunity via sharing rule, but he is not able to change the Territory value in Opportunity.

User is getting the error - "**insufficient access rights on cross-reference id**"

Do we need to provide any other permission so that he will be able to change the territory lookup value.

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tm2_assign_territory_to_opportunity_manually.htm&type=5) documentation below user permission is required to assign opportunity to territory manually.

REQUIRED EDITIONS AND USER PERMISSIONS

> Available in: Salesforce Classic for some features and Lightning
> Experience for all features
>
> Available in: Performance and Developer Editions and in Enterprise and
> Unlimited Editions with the Sales Cloud

USER PERMISSIONS NEEDED

> To assign opportunities to any territory in the active model in
> Lightning Experience: Full access to the opportunities’ parent
> accounts
>
> To assign opportunities to any territory in the active model in
> Salesforce Classic:   View access or higher to the opportunities’ parent accounts

Comment: I had a look at this documentation. I am trying in lightning and making the same user as owner of Account. Still no luck!